# How to fit height to screen?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to fit this responsive webpage to the browser height (no vertical scrolling) and I am puzzled.. All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy.

**HTML:**

```
  <header class="mainHeader">
  <a href="/home/show">
    <img src="/assets/EagleLogo.png" alt="" />
  </a>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="/products/supertherm" class="hvr-underline-from-center">SuperTHERM<sup>®</sup></a></li>
        <li><a href="/products/rustgrip" class="hvr-underline-from-center">RustGRIP<sup>®</sup></a></li>
        <li><a href="/products/hotpipe" class="hvr-underline-from-center">Hot-PIPE<sup>®</sup></a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="search"><a href="#"><img src="/assets/mg.png" alt="" /></a>
      </div>
      <div class="product-inventory"><a href="/products/index"><img src="/assets/inventory.png" alt="" /></a>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>

<hr>

  <div class="mainContent-container">
    <img class="thermal" src="/assets/thermal.png" alt="" />
    <img class="corrosion effect2"src="/assets/co.png" alt=""/>
    <img class="fire effect2"src="/assets/fire.png" alt="" />
       <p class="intro"></p>
  </div>

  <img src="/assets/phone.png" alt="" height="75px" width="75px" align="middle" />

  <footer class="mainFooter">  </footer>
```

**CSS:**

```
.mainHeader img {
width: 30%;
height: auto;
}

.mainHeader nav {
height: 40px;
margin-top: -4%;
text-align: center;
}

div.mainContent-container {
// width: 80%;
margin: 3% 10% -3% 10%;
position: relative;
list-style: none;

.intro {
padding: .1% 1% 0 1%;
margin-top: 1%;
width: 95%;
text-align: center;
font-size: 1.5em;
font-family: 'Raleway';
font-weight: 500;
}

img[src="/assets/phone.png"] {
margin: 3.5% 46.9% 4% 46.9%;
}

.mainFooter {
 margin: 0 0 5% 28.3%;
}
```

Comment: To fit the height of the screen use 'height: 100vh' for the width use 'width:100vw;'.

Answer (score 2):

> All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy.

This has to be the most extremely confusing saying I've ever read.

As for your question, it has been answered many, many times before.

Furthermore, it might not be very responsive to make everything fit height-wise, rather, you should focus on the width.

For instance, take a phone that's flipped horizontally, it would squish the design far too much.

If you insist..

```
html,body{height:100%;margin:0 0;padding:0 0;}
```

Comment: It seems like the fillers were introduced to bypass Stackoverflow's requirement for post length. Attempting to edit out the filler will show the complaint that the post is "Mostly Code"

Comment: You're clever. That makes sense. Still, quite a wise saying if I must say.